# creating a framebuffer to take an image from external oes

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to do multi pass rendering with framebuffer the issue is that the source is the camera so the texInput is not of type GL_TEXTURE_2D it is of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES tho, if I use the function glTexImage2D it gives a black screen when I use that texture in the future after rendering to it without any errors glErros.

On the other hand if I don't use it(because it does not support GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES) it gives me framebuffer status of NOT_COMPLETE

here is my code for creating the framebuffer and the texture that I want to associate to it.

```
fun prepareFBO() {
    val intArray = IntArray(1)
    glGenFramebuffers(1, intArray, 0)
    fboId = intArray.first()
    glGenTextures(1, intArray, 0)
    texId = intArray.first()
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,1080, 1920, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0)
    val status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)
    Log.e(TAG, "prepareFBO: ${status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE}")
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
}
```

the rest is just normal glDrawArrays and glActiveTexture that already works fine when I draw directly to the default framebuffer, if needed please let me know and I will share them.

Thanks for help!

UPDATE:
I found that I need instead of using glTexImage2d I can use eglBindTexImage instead so the final code is:

```
fun prepareFBO() {
    val intArray = IntArray(1)
    glGenFramebuffers(1, intArray, 0)
    fboId = intArray.first()
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId)

    glGenTextures(1, intArray, 0)
    texId = intArray.first()
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texId)
    checkGlError("Error 1")

    eglBindTexImage(eglGetCurrentDisplay(), windowSurface!!.eglSurface, EGL_BACK_BUFFER)

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texId, 0)
    val status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)
    Log.e(TAG, "prepareFBO: is status complete? => ${status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE}")
}
```

while this looks like it makes sense, still I am getting the status of the framebuffer as not complete :/

Comment: Are you trying to sample *from* an external texture, or render *to* an external texture? I don't think the latter is possible. As for the former, I'm not sure I understand why you would want to attach it to a framebuffer object.

Comment: @Andrea thanks for reply, I wanted to do gaussian blurring while dealing with input external oes textures, in order to do multipass rendering, I need to get oes texture(camera frame) use it as input into a framebuffer with a certain program that blurs in one direction then use the texture of that framebuffer as input and render the second pass on the default framebuffer with the same program with a different direction param that blurs in the other direction. Please help I am so desperate to do it :( have been in this for months now.

Comment: I think your problems are coming from trying to attach an external texture to a framebuffer object. You don't need to do that to sample from a texture. Instead you can bind it as a texture (not to a framebuffer object) and sample from it, and then render to a framebuffer object that has a normal texture (not the external one) attached.

Comment: This sounds like it is the right thing to do but I don't understand the part after bind it but not to a frame buffer, I understand how to bind it but not to a framebuffer but I don't understand your sentence: "and sample from it, and then render to a framebuffer object that has a normal texture" can you please give me an example in a separate answer so that I can accept it and give it reputation. @Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problems are coming from trying to attach an external texture to a framebuffer object.

Instead of trying to attach it to a framebuffer, perhaps try sampling from it in the usual way? That is:

- Pick a texture unit, e.g. `GL_TEXTURE0`, and activate it with `glActiveTexture`
- Bind the texture to that texture unit with `glBindTexture`
- Put the ID of the texture unit into a uniform with `glUniform1i` (the ID would be `0` if you used `GL_TEXTURE0` earlier, `1` if you used `GL_TEXTURE1`, etc)
- Draw something (e.g. with `glDrawArrays`) that uses the texture

I don't think I can provide useful sample code, but this is the normal way of using textures so there's going to be many examples of it out there. I assume you need to use `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` rather than `GL_TEXTURE_2D` when calling `glBindTexture` however.

You can still have a framebuffer object for drawing to if you want to, just not for reading from.

Comment: well the problem with this is that it is going to draw directly to the default framebuffer which I am sure it does not do the job. I have to render it at least once before rendering to the def framebuf. I already have the oes tex working with main buffer directly but I can't do multipass rendering if the input is oes. Maybe I think it is my problem that I asked the question in a wrong way, I think I should have said "I want to do multipass rendering with oes external tex as the input texture" If u think this is different question let me know I will ask another one and I will tag u.

Comment: You can create a framebuffer object for drawing to, you don't have to use the default framebuffer

Comment: but as far as I know I think that framebuffers won't work if the bound tex if oes, am I right? Looks like there is a concept that I don't understand here but let me tell you what I have tried and did not work. I got the frame from the camera through surfacet

Comment: I think I started to understand, you mean I send the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES though glUniform1i 

Comment: after thinking for a while it looks like u r right, I will implement that and check if it works, I really appreciate your answer looks like it is correct.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what I'm suggesting. I'm pretty sure that's how external textures are intended to be used. You might need to use some extension in the GLSL to make a valid shader, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I have applied what you told me and it does not work, only the second pass works :( I have created another question with the whole code. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783232/i-cant-do-multipass-rendering-if-the-bound-texture-is-of-type-gl-texture-extern 
I am sorry for bothering.