# I can't do multipass rendering if the bound texture is of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES in android opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to do multipass rendering using framebuffers and an input texture that is coming from the camera which means it is of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES

here is the full code that does not work(btw I am sure that the shaders work fine because I tried them with normal tex2d and they worked just fine and the rendering was perfect.)

first I have

```
val fboIds = IntArray(1)
val texIds = IntArray(1)

fun prepareFramebuffer() {
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fboIds, 0)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[0])

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texIds, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0])
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, videoResolution.width, videoResolution.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    glTexParameterf(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST.toFloat()
    )
    glTexParameterf(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL_LINEAR.toFloat()
    )
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    )
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    )
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0], 0)
    val status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)
    Timber.d("FRAMEBUFFER-STATUS is complete? ${status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE}") //I get true!
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
}
```

Then the draw function

```
fun draw(
    mvpMatrix: FloatArray?,
    vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer?,
    firstVertex: Int,
    vertexCount: Int,
    coordsPerVertex: Int,
    vertexStride: Int,
    texMatrix: FloatArray?,
    texBuffer: FloatBuffer?,
    textureId: Int,
    texStride: Int,
    maskBitmapOverlay: Bitmap?,
    mainFrameMaskTextureId: Int
) {

    glUseProgram(programHandle)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixLoc, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
    
    glUniformMatrix4fv(texMatrixLoc, 1, false, texMatrix, 0)
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        positionLoc, coordsPerVertex,
        GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer
    )
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordLoc)
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        textureCoordLoc, 2,
        GL_FLOAT, false, texStride, texBuffer
    )
    
    //textureId is of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3)
    glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId)

    //mainFrameMaskTextureId is of type GL_TEXTURE_2D
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
    glBindTexture(mainFrameMaskTarget, mainFrameMaskTextureId)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(mainFrameMaskTarget, 0, GL_RGBA, maskBitmapOverlay, 0)

    ...
    //other glUnifomrs
    ...
    glUniform1i(sTextureLoc, 3)
    glUniform1i(mainFrameMaskLoc, 1)
    glUniform1i(blurringDirectionLoc, 1)//this setting will change in the second pass, unfortunately the error is here since when I set this to glUniform1i(blurringDirectionLoc, 0) in the second pass it overrides what glUniform1i(blurringDirectionLoc, 1) does 


    //bind the framebuffer here.
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[0])

    //draw the first pass.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, firstVertex, vertexCount)
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays")

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0])
    glUniform1i(blurringDirectionLoc, 0)

    //draw the second pass.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, firstVertex, vertexCount)

    // Done -- disable vertex array, texture, and program.
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordLoc)
    glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0)
    glUseProgram(0)
}
```

What is the problem with code?
textureId is of type GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES and I think this is causing the framebuffer not to work I am not sure but the output I get looks like the first draw does not happen at all.

Comment: What is `textureTarget`?

Comment: @Andrea
sorry for that it is GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES I will update that in the question

Comment: I am also using this in the shader, it is working fine in the one pass rendering
"""#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
could it be causing a problem?

Comment: Have you checked for errors with glGetError()?